# Can we represent a++ + ++a + a++ as an expression tree?

Tags: expression-trees

I'm confused in construction of expression trees for unary operators like negation(-), post/pre-increment(++), post/pre-decrement(--).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on language, `(a++) + (++a) + (a++)` is perfectly legal, is undefined behaviour or is a downright compile error.

In a perfectly legal case, I would imagine it to be like

```
expression = unary_op operand | operand unary_op | operand binary_op operand
operand = literal | expression
unary_op = ++ | --
binary_op = + | - | * | /
expressions must be evaluated from left to right
```

Hence the expression tree in prefix notation would be

```
tree = unary_op{tree} | binary_op{tree, tree} | literal
```

Note that we differentiate pre/post increment/decrement in the tree representation.
The sample expression would have a tree of `+{+{++_post{a}, ++_pre{a}}, ++_post{a}}` evaluated in dfs.

In the case of undefined behaviour, it is likely that the language says the order of which the operations are evaluated is not specified, meaning `(++a) / (++a)` may be less than or greater than 1.

In the case of compile error, the language just says: we are not going into this mess.

Answer (score 0):

The parser needs to distinguish the various operators syntactically, and then it doesn't matter that they're all spelled using the same character. The expression tree shouldn't care about spelling.

Perhaps it's easier to see if you substitute new spelling, say `$` for pre-increment and `@` for post-increment:

```
A @ + $ A + A @
```

Since it's already been parsed, might as well normalize all the unary operators to prefix notation:

```
@ A + $ A + @ A
```